# Field History using GetRelatedListRecords

Tags: lightning-web-components

Does anyone know if you can use the GetRelatedListRecords method in LWC to retrieve field history from a custom object (called Animal__c).  The intention is to use chart.js to plot the changes in some numerical data captured over time.

The start of my code looks like this, is this valid?

```
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import CHART_JS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/ChartJS23';

export default class WeightHistoryChart extends LightningElement {
    chartInitialized = false;

    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '$recordId',
        relatedListId: 'Animal__History',
        fields: ['CreatedDate', 'OldValue', 'NewValue'],
        where: "{ field: 'Animal__History.Field', value: 'Current_Weight__c'}"})
        weightHistoryData;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible retrieve history records, but you have to change few paramenters:

- `relatedListId` must be the relationship name, so `Histories`.
- `fields` must be an array of string with the following format: *objectApiName.fieldApiName*. So in your case it should be: `['Animal__History.CreatedDate', 'Animal__History.OldValue', 'Animal__History.NewValue']`
- `where` clause should be in [GraphQL syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/graphql/guide/filter-fields.html) as stated in [`getRelatedListRecords` documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-get-related-list-records.html), so `{ Field : { eq: "Current_Weight__c" } }`

These changes result in the following code:

```js
@wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
    parentRecordId: '$recordId',
    relatedListId: 'Histories',
    fields: ['Animal__History.CreatedDate', 'Animal__History.OldValue', 'Animal__History.NewValue'],
    where: '{ Field : { eq: "Current_Weight__c" } }'
    })
    weightHistoryData;
```